# NSURLConnection and the corresponding device type

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, device

For the iPad, iPhone, iTouch app that talk to remote web service by making NSURLConnection calls, is there a way for the remote service to tell what kind of device that the call is made from?

Basically, how I can know the device type of the device on which my app is running?

Answer (score 0):

The USER_AGENT string on the server will include the device type.

Comment: I tried on the server side by getting the USER_AGENT thru the HTTP header for the calls made on the device via NSURLConnection, it returned me <my app name>/1.0, and that's it. :(